# Laravel Eager Loading Order By date/other fields and last record inside the relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have 3 models with the fields

```
LEAD
    id
    first_name
    surname

//in lead model
public function trxn()
{
    return $this->hasMany('lead_trxn', 'lead_id', 'id');
}

LEAD_TRXN
    id
    lead_id
    create_datetime
    expiration_datetime
    status

//in lead_trxn model
public function detail()
{
    return $this->hasMany('lead_trxn_details', 'lead_trxn_id', 'id');
}

LEAD_TRXN_DETAILS
    id
    lead_trxn_id
    product_id
    create_datetime
    status
```

And I have this to retrieve the records using Eager loading

```
$leads = Lead::with(
                    array
                         (
                             'trxn' => function($qry)
                             {
                                 $qry->with(
                                               array
                                               (
                                                   'details'
                                                   //i need the last inserted product here
                                               )
                                           );

                                  //i need to order it by expiration date
                                  //$qry->orderBy('expiration_date');
                             }
                         )
                   )->get();
```

Question 1:
How can I sort it by expiration date or create_datetime in lead_trxn in a way its a dynamic filter? Meaning, if I plot the data into a table, and I click the header of the table, it will sort the records based on the header I have clicked.

Question 2:
How can I get the last product_id inserted in lead_trxn_details?

Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: 1 `joins` are the only way, 2 Not sure what you mean, but I suppose this is what you want http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/

Answer (score -1):

Since you get the column order and direction from users, You need to pass both column and direction into the query. Therefore you can extend the query with `orderBy` function inside the closure.

```
   $leads = Lead::with(array( 'trxn' => function($qry) use($orderByColumn, $direction) {
      $qry->orderBy($orderByColumn, $direction)
        ->with( array ( 'details' => function($q) {
            $q->orderBy('create_datetime', 'desc')->first(); // get the latest inserted product
          })
      );
    }
  )
 )->get();
```

Comment: how if i would like to sort it ascending? or can i add requirement to question 1? how if i want to add more filter in lead_trxn? sorry I think i forgot to specify it earlier.

Comment: @Ponce I updated my code. please try it and let me know.

Comment: @Ponce I think I got solution for both questions. Please try and let me know the result. :)